# How to write in proper format of this equation

Tags: equations, align

How to put in proper format in equation proof.

```
\begin{align*}
    HS_{opt} \le (HS_1+HS_2+ .... +HS_i)+ {HSi * ((A \textnormal{-} taskarea)/HS_i)} \\
    \Longrightarrow HS_{opt} \le HS{frac}
\end{align*}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the following is a starting point:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\HS}{\text{HS}}

\begin{document}

From~(1) and~(2) we obtain
\begin{align*}
  \HS_{\text{opt}} &\leq (\HS_1 + \HS_2 + \dots + \HS_i) + \HS_i \times \bigl( (A\text{-taskarea}) \div \HS_i \bigr) \\
  \Longrightarrow \HS_{\text{opt}} &\leq \HS_{\text{frac}}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

For consistency, you could define macros for repeatedly-used elements. Also, [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) provides `\text{<stuff>}` for setting text inside math-mode.

Note the use of `&` to identify the alignment points *before* the relation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that uses a `gather*` environment instead of an `align*` environment. Just as @Werner does in his answer, I would recommend that you write variable names in an upright-text font face instead of a math-italic font face.

[image]

I will admit to not being certain how the string "A-taskarea" should be typeset. In the code above, I've chosen to typeset it in an upright-roman type face.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\HS{\textrm{HS}}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
    \HS_{\textrm{opt}} \le (\HS_1+\HS_2+ \dots +\HS_i)+ {\HS_i \times (\textrm{A-taskarea})/\HS_i)} \\
    \Longrightarrow \HS_{\textrm{opt}} \le \HS_{\textrm{frac}}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```